# Could not authenticate download server. You may be experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, sdk

yesterday i tried to build apk using command line . Then it's automatically updates dart sdk. but it's not completely done. after that it's showing the errors..

```
flutter doctor
Downloading android-arm-release/linux-x64 tools...                      
Could not authenticate download server. You may be experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack,
your network may be compromised, or you may have malware installed on yourcomputer.URL:https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/flutter/0f90e6546bf302bda9b1e8213a004ed5c16d13c4/android-arm-release/linux-x64.zip
```

Comment: And I assume you’re not running anything that could be misinterpreted as MITM issue (e.g., something observing network activity like Charles or Wireshark)?

Comment: no i am not using these

Comment: Is it solved,brother?

Answer (score 0):

- I disconnected the VPN( Internet was still there)
- Opened command prompt in adminstrator mode.
- Executed "flutter doctor"
- It automatically downloaded all required files.
- Connected back my VPN.

Now Flutter is fine